# Ayuda para migrar Laravel 5.2 a Producción

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel, base-de-datos

He estado buscando en internet y he encontrado diferentes respuestas pero ninguna se acerca a lo que busco. Necesito migrar una aplicación de **Laravel 5.2** de mi servidor local a uno remoto y para eso, necesito crear su correspondiente base de datos.

Mi problema concreto es que no sé cómo instrumentar las migraciones de Laravel para recrear las tablas en la nueva BD.

He probado con `php artisan migrate:reset` y `php artisan migrate:truncate` y siempre se crean un par de tablas, pero no todas...

¿Cómo debería hacer?

Comment: No me queda muy claro cual es el problema, ¿no se están generando las tablas con las migraciones? ¿es un problema relacionado con alguna herramienta de "deploy"? ¿Es automático o manual el proceso de migración?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi solución fue utilizar `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan optimize` y luego `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`.

Esto solucionó problemas que tenía con `migrate:rollback` y `migrate:reset`. Gracias de todas formas...

Comment: Sería importante que la próxima vez respondas los comentarios o comentes en las otras respuestas si algo sirvió o no.

Comment: @Shaz bueno, me respondí a mi mismo proque encontré la solución por mi cuenta, no por los comentarios de arriba. En cambio, cuando los leí ya lo había solucionado y a fin de cuentas no decían lo que realmente me sirvió.

Answer (score 1):

Me ha pasado que no se crean mis tablas cuando tienen relaciones. 
Para solucionar el problema primero creo las tablas que no reciben la relación y después las que si tienen la llave foránea.

Para regresar las tablas usa

### php artisan migrate:rollback

Comment: bueno... recapitulando:  no me sirvió, Me dio error porque las tablas ya existían.

Answer (score 0):

Has probado con:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Desde el server de producción debes ejecutar este comando, con la base de datos vacía, esto ejecuta todas las migraciones programadas.

Comment: No puedo dar migrate porque me aparece que las tablas existen. Gracias igual

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar el siguiente comando:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Si tienes seeders que ejecutar a continuación de la migración, lo puede hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

Comment: fue lo que puse arriba

Comment: Arriba, en tu pregunta pusiste "reset" y yo te puse que usaras "refresh"...son distintas opciones. Evidentemente te sirvió.

Comment: Si te fijas, mi respuesta fue anterior a la tuya. Gracias igual.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya tienes tu base de datos completa y funcionando en local, la forma fácil de llevarla al servidor de producción, y de paso guardar una copia de seguridad, será ***hacer un volcado del SQL*** desde un gestor como *phpMyAdmin* y usar ese mismo SQL para recrearla en el servidor, nuevamente con ayuda de un gestor.